# iPhone CATextLayer doesn't show its text

Tags: ios, iphone, user-interface

I was simply trying to add a `CATextlayer` in an `UIView` layer. However, according to the following code, I only get the `CATextlayer`'s background color to be displayed in the `UIView`, without any text. Just wonder what I missed to display the text.

Could anyone offer a hint/sample how to use `CATextlayer`?

```
  - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
        if ((self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil])) {
            // Custom initialization

            CATextLayer *TextLayer = [CATextLayer layer];
            TextLayer.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f, 100.0f);
            TextLayer.string = @"Test";
            TextLayer.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18].fontName;
            TextLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
            TextLayer.wrapped = NO;

            //TextLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
            self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f, 100.0f)];
            self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
            [self.view.layer addSublayer:TextLayer];
            [self.view.layer layoutSublayers];

        }
        return self;
    }
```

Comment: I know this is old post, but the problem here is that you add textlayer to the view that you manually created, but you didn't add the view to your current view.

Answer (score 7):

For iOS 5 and beyond, one can use CATextLayer as follows:

```cs
CATextLayer *textLayer = [CATextLayer layer];
textLayer.frame = CGRectMake(144, 42, 76, 21);
textLayer.font = CFBridgingRetain([UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18].fontName);
textLayer.fontSize = 18;
textLayer.foregroundColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
textLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor].CGColor;
textLayer.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentCenter;
textLayer.string = @"BAC";
[self.view.layer addSublayer:textLayer];
```

You can add this code in any function you like. Specially here correct assignment of *font* is necessary, otherwise your CATextLayer will be rendered as black no matter what textColor you set.

Answer (score 5):

Change your code to this:

```
CATextLayer *TextLayer = [CATextLayer layer];
TextLayer.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f, 100.0f);
TextLayer.string = @"Test";
TextLayer.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18].fontName;
TextLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
TextLayer.position = CGPointMake(80.0, 80.0f);
TextLayer.wrapped = NO;
[self.view.layer addSublayer:TextLayer];
```

You should also be doing this in the view controller's -viewDidLoad. That way you know your view is loaded and valid and can now have layers added to it.

Comment: Looks like he was trying in a UIView subclass which doesn't have a viewDidLoad. I tried your code in the 'layoutSubviews' method and it worked. Not sure what the best place for a UIView would be.

Answer (score 5):

You should (counter-intuitively) call `textLayer.display()` or `textLayer.displayIfNeeded()` after the initialization is complete or whenever you want it to draw text.

Answer (score 4):

## Swift

Here is an example that shows a view with a CATextLayer using a custom font with colored text.

[image]

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myView: UIView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // Attributed string
        let myAttributes = [
            NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Chalkduster", size: 30.0)! , // font
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.cyanColor()             // text color
        ]
        let myAttributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "My text", attributes: myAttributes )
        
        // Text layer
        let myTextLayer = CATextLayer()
        myTextLayer.string = myAttributedString
        myTextLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
        myTextLayer.frame = myView.bounds
        myView.layer.addSublayer(myTextLayer)
    }
}
```

My fuller answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38835131/3681880).

Answer (score 2):

You can customize the CLTextLayer Like this,

```
    CATextLayer *aTextLayer_= [[CATextLayer alloc] init];

aTextLayer_.frame =CGRectMake(23.0, 160.0, 243.0, 99.0);

aTextLayer_.font=CTFontCreateWithName( (CFStringRef)@"Courier", 0.0, NULL);

    aTextLayer_.string = @"You string put here";

aTextLayer_.wrapped = YES;

aTextLayer_.foregroundColor = [[UIColor greenColor] CGColor];

aTextLayer_.fontSize = 15.f;

   aTextLayer_.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;

aTextLayer_.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentCenter;

[self.view.layer addSublayer:aTextLayer_];
```

Don,t forgot to import CoreText/CoreText.h in your view-class. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, the default text color of a `CATextLayer` is white. White on white is hard to see.

Comment: Thanks for your post!
After I changed color to black, still no text shown. Any further recommendation?

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f, 100.0f)];
[self.view setWantsLayer:YES];
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```